# convert an int pointer to any object pointer, then call it's methods. it works

Tags: c++, pointers

I encounter some strange things in C++, but I don't know why?

I have a class like this

header file

```
class foo
{
public:
    void call_foo();

    int get_foo();

    int get_foo(int val);
};
```

here is the cpp file

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo::call_foo()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 33;
    cout << i + j << endl;
    cout << "Hello, Foo" << endl;
}

int foo::get_foo(int val)
{
    int a = 345;
    int rc = val + a;
    cout << rc << endl;
    return rc;
}

int foo::get_foo()
{
    int a = 100;
    int d = 23;
    int rc = a + d;

    cout << rc << endl;
    return rc;
}
```

I using code to test as below

```
int main()
{
    int* val = new int[100];

    foo* foo_ptr;
    foo_ptr = (foo*)val;
    foo_ptr->call_foo();
    foo_ptr->get_foo();
    foo_ptr->get_foo(100);

    delete [] val;
    return 0;
}
```

then i compile and execute it.

```
clang++ foo.cpp main.cpp
```

Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)
os x 10.9

an int pointer convert to an object pointer, then call it's methods, it work! so weird!
Is there anybody know what is going on?

**I wrote an article on [my blog](http://endwan.com/blog/2013/10/31/c-plus-plus-arbitrarily-pointer-convert-to-an-object-pointer/) about why it works in my understood, Thanks all of you!! about object structure, virtual function table. just Chinese version :)**

Comment: `C++` lets you get away with doing things that aren't allowed, under the name *undefined behaviour*. Basically, it means "if you do something stupid, we won't stop you, but absolutely anything could happen"!

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior.  The only reason this works is because `foo` has no data members and no virtual functions (so no `vtable`).  The methods for `foo` are all in the same location (regardless of the instance), so you won't be squashing memory.

Comment: I wouldn't say "the only reason this works", so much as "the only reason this doesn't crash, and *appears* to work"!

Comment: the object actual not instantiated, why can access it's methods? i added a data member, it still works. :(

Comment: @EnderWan: You can't call the functions; there's just nothing to stop you trying, with undefined behaviour if you do. That behaviour *might* call the functions (as it does for you); or it might crash, corrupt other data, or do anything else you can think of.

Comment: Not at all surprising.  In some environments you can likely even access data members (which would be overlaid over your int array).

Comment: I really understood what is heppen! thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called Undefined Behavior.

Undefined Behavior means "anything can happen."  *Anything* here includes the illusion that your code worked, did something you expected it to do, or *didn't* do something you expected it to do -- like crash.

Code that evokes Undefined Behavior is always faulty code.  You cannot rely on Undefined Behavior, if simply for the reason that you cannot predict what will happen.

Now in this case, the reason why calling the methods might appear to work is because in practice an instance of a class doesn't get it's own copy of the code for each of the non-`static` methods.  Instead, there's one copy of the code that is shared between all instances of `foo`.  The pointer to that code never changes, so when you (incorrectly) resolve a pointer-to-`foo` and then call one of the methods through that pointer, the actual method you expected to call was actually called.  This is all still Undefined Behavior however, and you need to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour and your program is ill-formed. As far as language specification is concerned, anything could happen.

It just happens to appear to work because no member function access any data that would belong to a particular instance of `foo` objects. All they do is allocate local data and access `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, it has undefined behaviour.

However, the functions aren't virtual, and the object has no data members, so it's likely that your program won't actually touch the invalid memory, and so will have the same effect as calling the functions on a valid object.

Comment: @Raxvan:  The example provided *appears* to work.  Code which exhibits Undefined Behavior is, by definition, ill-formed.  It's **not** working.

Comment: @Raxvan: No, it's behaving in some undefined manner. My answer explains why it's likely to look like it's "working" (if by "working", you mean "behaving as if the object were valid").

Comment: by working i mean that is runs and executes properly. What do you refer to when you say that is `undefined behaviour` ?

Comment: @Raxvan: I mean that the language standard doesn't define what the code should do, so it could do anything. There's no concept of executing "properly", since there is no "proper" behaviour for this code: it is allowed to do absolutely anything. It may behave, for you, as it would if `foo_ptr` pointed to a valid object - I assume that's what you mean by "properly". But another compiler could make the function calls crash, wipe your hard drive, or order pizza.

Comment: I added a data member and it works too, i want to know why a class not instantiated, it can access methods and data member?

Comment: Well i understand your point now; custom allocators usually do this stuff, except they call the constructor using placement new and destructor called manually; For me this quite often and i find quite hard to see the problem in such code design.

Comment: @EnderWan: Sorry to keep repeating myself, but **it does not work**. Calling member functions on an invalid object (as you do here) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I access data member crashed when call it without main function. i just want know want what is happen. is it behaviour depends compiler?

Comment: @EnderWan: The behaviour will depend on the compiler, but the important point is that it is **undefined**: the compiler is allowed to do anything it likes. It will generate code which will work if the object is valid, but could do anything (crash, or appear to work some or all the time, or corrupt the program state, or anything else) if it isn't. In this case, with your compiler, it calls the functions; they don't access the object (or, if they do, access part of your allocated memory instead); and so nothing particularly disastrous happens. But that behaviour is **not** guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has no members and no virtual functions so when you call a member function through any arbitrary pointer it will 'work' since you have a statically bound function call and don't do any memory access that would be invalid. Bad things would happen if you tried to call a virtual function or access a member variable.